# PHP DOM append HTML in Wordpress filter

Tags: php, wordpress, dom, append, appendchild

I created a Wordpress filter using the DOM API method that was suggested here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/61036/103233 to change some attributes of my images:

```
function add_lazyload($content) {

    $content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);

    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {  
        $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
        $node->setAttribute('data-src', $oldsrc );
        $newsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/placeholder.gif';
        $node->setAttribute('src', $newsrc);
    }

    $newHtml = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML()));
    return $newHtml;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_lazyload');
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'add_lazyload');
```

How can I add a HTML element within the `foreach` loop?

I tried adding a new `DOMDocument` and displaying it within the loop:

```
$test = new DOMDocument();
$test->loadHTML('<a>Hello</a>');
$test->saveHTML();
```

But this first prints all new `$test` elements (one for each loop) and then my altered `$newHTML` is printed. I want to append the new `$test` element to each `img` of the `foreach` loop. I never used DOM before... any suggestions? `appendChild`? But how?

Comment: Do you want to append the `$test` node inside an `img`? Or do you want to add it after / before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php is the way to go. So you'd do something like:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {  
    $oldsrc = $node->getAttribute('src');
    $node->setAttribute('data-src', $oldsrc );
    $newsrc = get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/placeholder.gif';
    $node->setAttribute('src', $newsrc);

    // Create new anchor
    $testNode = $dom->createElement('a', 'Hello');
    $node->appendChild($testNode); // Insert new node inside (bad idea for images though)
    $node->parentNode->appendChild($testNode); // Insert new node after image
    $node->parentNode->insertBefore($testNode, $node); // Insert new node before image
}
```

You need to be careful with appending text with createElement as HTML entities such as `&` ampersands need to be escaped.

Comment: Also when you output your node, so you don't need to do replace all the gumpth around it just do: $doc->saveHTML($node); the node is the context of where it will start exporting your html.

Comment: We're an the right track here, thanks man! You're right, the element should be appended after the image. 

Problem: When I use your code, the `<a>Hello</a>`elements are all printed after all images are printed. But I'm trying to print every single image and the new element right after that.

The final thing will be a `<noscript>` element after each image as a lazyload fallback...

Comment: The "insertBefore" works though... So i'll use that!

Comment: One last question: Let's say the element I want to append is the original image before it was altered... I tried to add something like `$fallback = $node;` at the beginning of the loop and than used this in the insertBefore at the end: `$node->parentNode->insertBefore($fallback, $node); `... Didn't work since I have no idea what I'm doing here :/

Comment: You need to clone the node, use `$fallback = $node->cloneNode(true);` The `true` param means clone deep and not just that individual node. The PHP documentation for Dom is actually pretty decent... there are a few gotchas we've faced but they're mostly described on the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! This created an endless loop... `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in ... line ...`. I added `$fallback = $node->cloneNode(true);` as the first line within the loop and `$node->parentNode->insertBefore($fallback, $node); ` at the last line within the loop.

Comment: Ok yes, this can happen with a DomNodeList, as altering the Dom whilst iterating over it can cause it to loop forever... the DomNodeList when iterating is actually a pointer... so if you keep appending new images than it'll keep looping. You can get around this by adding the nodes found by your `getElementsByTagName()` to an array. Then iterate over your array instead of the DomNodeList directly.

Comment: You are so right.. that was stupid. Works like a charm – thank you, sir!